# NGINX RP as gateway to all my LAN services

Tags: nginx-reverse-proxy

I'm trying to setup a Reverse Proxy based on NGinx on a Raspberry.

What I have :
- 1 synology server at home (location 1)
- 1 synology server at one of my friends' home (location 2)
- 1 Raspberry with Raspbian & Nginx RP (RPi_NGinx)
- 1 Raspberry with Raspbian & self hosted Jitsi meet server (Rpi_Jitsi)
- 1 Raspberry with Raspbian & PiVPN (OpenVPN server)
- 1 Asus Router

I only have one external IP and one domain name (let's say: myowndomain.com) and I can set as many CNAME.

[See Diagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I9wZq.png)

What I want to do is setup NGinx so I can 
- connect from internet to my synology NAS (SynoHome) , using dsm.myowndomain.com
- connect from internet to my router , using rtr.myowndomain.com
- connect from internet to my jitsi meet self hosted server router , using jitsi.myowndomain.com
- connect from internet over VPN to other home ressources on my LAN using vpn.myowndomain.com
- make sure my other synology (SynoBackup) will continue to replicate with  my SynoHome,

What I already did:
- Setup NGinx
- Configured some /etc/nginx/sites-available/xxx.myowndomain.com.conf,
- Configured some links on /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/xxx.myowndomain.com.conf,
- modified win/sys32/drivers/etc/host in order to test my setup from inside my network

All my xxx.myowndomain.com.conf look like:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name dsm.myowndomain.com;
    location / {

    proxy_pass https://192.168.200.200:5001;
    }
```

}

So far I can only access to my Synology Admin UI. All other uses cases tests leads either to 502 Bad Gateway, or to a deadloop (Asus Router WebGUI) that reloads the same page.

Some NGINX expert who wants to help a noob?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Try it like this:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name dsm.myowndomain.com;
    location / {
    proxy_pass https://192.168.200.200:5001/ /;
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi, It dosesn't work with the 2 / / at the end. Tried by keeping only on (just after the port num, but does not work either.